# How do we say "domestic apples" in normal English

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

If you are serving apple pie and you want to write the menu so that the customer understands that the apples in the pie are from THE VERY CITY that the restaurant is in, how can I rewrite this phrase:

> Home-made apple pie, with DOMESTIC
>   apples grown right here in San Diego.

I feel like the word 'domestic' refers to meat, but is there a good word for a menu that refers to local produce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Domestic* refers not so much to meat as the animals it came from. It can sometimes be used to mean "local", but only as opposed to "imported from abroad", not as in "locally-grown".

I think *locally-grown* is your best bet on a menu.

> Homemade apple pie with locally-grown apples from right here in San Diego.

Comment: Good point re: Domestic, and another good option.

Comment: *Domestic*, when used to describe produce, means "grown in this country", as opposed to *imported*. With regard to animals, the term *domesticated* is used to describe food animals that are not wild game, and *domestic* refers to pets.

Comment: Except that “adverbLY adjective” combinations do not take hyphens, since there is never any possible misreading of applying the adverb to the noun following.

Answer (score 8):

The only word I can think of that really fits there is *local*.

With that being said, given that you say "*grown right here in San Diego*", I'm not sure you need an adjective there.

Comment: +1 for "grown right here in San Diego" being sufficient on its own.

Comment: I agree; _grown right here_ is sufficient. "Local apples grown right here in San Diego" could be used to refer to apples native to San Diego, in contrast with a variety of apples that was native to a different place, and then cultivated also in San Diego.

Comment: @ Dusty: Thank you Dusty. I thought the very same thing but I was in too much of a hurry to reword it for the question. But I agree with you that adding the name of the place would remove the need for the adjective. Thanks for the hint.